# How to Order amount by multiple dimensions in MDX?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2

In my Cube,I have following Measures,Dimensions.

```
**Measure:**
Amount

**From Customer dimension:**
Busines Unit Number
Business Unit Description
Cust Number
Cust Name

**From Bucket dimension:**
Bucket
```

I want Amount to be ordered by all these dimensions/attributes.

What I tried in `MDX` so far is,

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { 

    [Measures].[Amount] 

} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY { (
ORDER(
    (
    [Dim Customer].[BU].[BU].MEMBERS*
    [Dim Customer].[BU Description].[BU Description].MEMBERS*
    [Dim Customer].[Cust No].[Cust No].ALLMEMBERS*
    [Dim Address].[Customer Name].[Customer Name].ALLMEMBERS
    ),
[Measures].[Amount],
BDESC
)

* 

[Bucket Dim].[Bucket].[Bucket].ALLMEMBERS 
) }  ON ROWS 

FROM [Cube]
```

Still I am not getting proper order as I want & also it is taking a too much time to execute.

Comment: What data type do you assume the first argument to `ORDER` has? According to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx), it should be a set. But you pass a comma separated list of sets in parentheses. Maybe you should make it a cross product of the four single dimensional sets, i. e. replacing the commas with `*`? That at least would be a set.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am done with the same, working now.

Comment: @FrankPl, we can also use , in braces. Whats the differen here using , & *

Comment: What a number of sets, separated by a comma, and all that in parentheses is is not defined by the MDX specification - as far as I know. Hence I have no idea how Analysis Services interprets it, as I never actually used that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest `ORDER` functions to get multiple order by criteria.

The outer order is applied first - a little counter-intuitive.

The following will be ordered by the value of `cust no`, then by the caption of `BU` then by `[Measures].[Amount]`

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        Order
        (
          Order
          (
            Order
            (
                [Dim Customer].[BU].[BU].MEMBERS*
                [Dim Customer].[BU Description].[BU Description].MEMBERS*
                [Dim Customer].[Cust No].[Cust No].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Dim Address].[Customer Name].[Customer Name].ALLMEMBERS
             ,[Measures].[Amount]
             ,BDESC
            )
           ,[Dim Customer].[BU].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
           ,BDESC
          )
         ,[Dim Customer].[Cust No].CurrentMember.MemberValue
         ,BDESC
        )
      * 
        [Bucket Dim].[Bucket].[Bucket].ALLMEMBERS
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```